# How to escape double dash in markdown?

Tags: markdown

When type -- in jekyll, markdown will replace `--` with `&#8211;`.
Is there any way to prevent this happen?

Comment: I consider this a feature - just found that Jupyter Notebook markdown does not produce m-dash there. But thanks to this question I could just copy and paste the right character entity ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Surround -- with ` can fix this problem.

e.g.

`--`

**[IMPROVED]**

Using rdiscount instead of Maruku to parse markdown can fix this problem

Answer (score 24):

You can escape markdown characters using a backslash (`\`). In this case you could type `\-\-`

Comment: I tried you suggestion, however, it seems not working...Thanks, anyway

Comment: This does work with the "kramdown" mode of markdown in Jekyll.

Comment: Works for me using rdiscount.

Answer (score 4):

Answer already accepted, but this is the proper solution.

To fix this in Jekyll, the default markdown library, Redcarpet, needs to include the smart extension.

```
_config.yml
    markdown: redcarpet
    redcarpet:
      extensions: ['smart']
```

It's in the [Jekyll docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/)

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this issue with Octopress, here is something working

```
-\\\\-
```

Comment: In Sphinx with myst, it was three of them: `-\\\-` for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it to work on XWiki using the code below:

`~-~-`

Comment: This worked for me inside a `<pre>` html tag